# Calling an XML report by clicking a button on Oracle form and downloading the output

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have an xml report defined which produces a pdf output when submitted from SRS window.
Now the same report needs to be called from form by clicking a button.

The report should run and the output must be available there itself as a downloadable pdf file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be done following two steps:
1- First you have to attach layout to your concurrent request using fnd_request.add_layout.
2- Then you have to submit the concurrent request using fnd_request.submit_request.

```
Your code goes as follows:
  --Setting Layout for the Request
  l_layout := apps.fnd_request.add_layout(
                            template_appl_name => 'XXCUST',
                            template_code      => 'XXEMP',
                            template_language  => 'en',
                            template_territory => 'US',
                            output_format      => 'EXCEL');
  --
  --Submitting Concurrent Request
  --
  l_request_id := fnd_request.submit_request ( 
                            application   => 'XXCUST', 
                            program       => 'XXEMP', 
                            description   => 'XXTest Employee Details', 
                            start_time    => sysdate, 
                            sub_request   => FALSE,
                            argument1     => 'Smith');
```

to get information about templates, you can use following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM xdo_templates_b
WHERE template_code = ‘FNDCPPGD_XML’;

SELECT * FROM xdo_templates_tl
WHERE template_code = ‘FNDCPPGD_XML’;
```

Comment: That's Ok. But how can I get the download output link on the form itself. I do not wan't to go and view the submitted reports and see the output from there.